# How do I insert text after a specific line in files using powershell?

Tags: powershell

As part of a huge refactoring I removed some duplicate classes and enums. I moved namespaces and restructured everything to be easier to maintain in the future.

All changes has been scripted already except for one thing. I need to insert a data contract namespace in every file that uses another namespace if the data contract namespace has not been inserted yet.

The code I have at the moment does not work but is sort of what I need I guess.

```
function Insert-Usings{
    trap {
        Write-Host ("ERROR: " + $_) -ForegroundColor Red
        return $false 
    }
    (Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Include *.asmx,*.ascx,*.cs,*.aspx -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue) | % {
    $fileName  = $_.FullName
    (Get-Content $fileName) | 
        Foreach-Object 
        {
            $_
            if ($_ -cmatch "using Company.Shared;") { 
                    $_ -creplace "using Company.Shared;", "using Company.Common;"
            }
            elseif ($_ -cmatch "using Company") {
                #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
                "using Company.Services.Contracts;"
            }
            else{
                $_
            }
        }
    } | Set-Content $fileName
}
```

**Edit:** The code tends to output (overwrite the whole file with-) "using Company.Services.Contracts" statements.

Comment: Does it fail? What is the error message? Or does it do something different from what you want?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear enough in the original question. I'll update with some more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you what to get exactly but I'll try to guess, see my comments in the code. The original code, I think, contains a few mistakes, one is serious: `Set-Content` is used in a wrong pipeline/loop. Here is the corrected code.

```
function Insert-Usings
{
    trap {
        Write-Host ("ERROR: " + $_) -ForegroundColor Red
        return $false
    }
    (Get-ChildItem $base_dir -Include *.asmx,*.ascx,*.cs,*.aspx -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue) | % {
        $fileName  = $_.FullName
        (Get-Content $fileName) | % {
            if ($_ -cmatch "using Company\.Shared;") {
                # just replace
                $_ -creplace "using Company\.Shared;", "using Company.Common;"
            }
            elseif ($_ -cmatch "using Company") {
                # write the original line
                $_
                # and add this after
                "using Company.Services.Contracts;"
            }
            else{
                # write the original line
                $_
            }
        } |
        Set-Content $fileName
    }
}
```

For example, it replaces this:

```
xxx

using Company.Shared;

using Company;

ttt
```

with this:

```
xxx

using Company.Common;

using Company;
using Company.Services.Contracts;

ttt
```

Note: presumably you should not apply this code to sources more than once, the code is not designed for this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you elaborate on the footnote about not being designed for this. Anything I can do to make it more safe? The code is not intended to be run more than once. It will be one step of a deployment routine and only run once per customer but do you see any ways I can improve the above code?

Comment: If you run this code second time, it will add some code after *each* line with `using Company`. This will be wrong because it was already done on the 1st run.  Just do not run it twice - I think it's the best simple solution. If some run fails in the middle then discard/kill all partially changed sources, take the original, run again after resolving problems.

Comment: Wish I could give you some more points for the helpful answers ;)

Comment: Alternatively, and much more safe, you may add and use a function/code that checks whether a file is already processed (contains new `using` s). In the main loop you call it first and then call `Insert-Usings` only if it is not yet done. Such a procedure can be safely called 2+ times on the same sources. Thus, it can be "resumed" after failures.